# How i can avoid hash added for Entity Framework to my entity name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Can someone help me understand why the entity's framework adds a "hash" or something like that to the name of the entity?

I have a named entity BankMovementHeader however, when the recovery of the DB with entity framework, brings me something like  `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.BankMovementHeader_D10A1C5179505A4186BA0005487B525128E7B58FBCA552E31ED17A33A4671673` do not know why the value `_D10A1C5179505A4186BA0005487B525128E7B58FBCA552E31ED17A33A4671673` is added.

This is bad for me because I want to use the entity to analyze it in an xml object.

Comment: try to modify your DbContext class like => `public YourDbContext() : base("name=YourDbContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }`

Comment: Thanks for response @ershoaib
How i can do that if my DbContext was created with Entity Framework (DB First Aproach)

Comment: for DB first approach, when u create your global variable for `DbContext` in your application then just set it as `_dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`

Comment: Very thanks @ershoaib, now it works fine.

Comment: I add this as answer to your question you just mark tick on left side of answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you use Entity Framework with `Code-First` approach. then modify your implementation of `DbContext` class like

```
public YourDbContext() : base("name=YourDbContext")
{
    //Your other configuration here
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

2) If you use Entity Framework with `Database-First` approach. Then set your global variable for `DbContext` in your application like.

```
_dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: @AdolfoMazariegos, glad to hear :)